# Netbeans 7 and XSLT support

Tags: xslt, netbeans-7

Does anyone knows how to enable XSLT support, auto-complete in particular, in Netbeans 7?
Every time I'm opening a new tag within my style, the auto-complete pop-up appears, and shows "downloading...". After few seconds it disappears and that's all.

Regards,
Radek

Comment: which version of the xslt support (xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0) you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/xml_schema_editor_in_netbeans

---

1. Go to Tools | Plugins in NetBeans IDE 7.0.1. In the Settings tab, register this update center:
   http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/xml/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml
2. Now go to the Available Plugins tab and search for XML Tools. Install that plugin.
3. Go to the New File dialog and pick an XML schema file

Comment: This seems to only add the xsd support.